# Convert Django model form based system into a raw HTML based form system for signup

Tags: python, html, django

I have a class-based view system for signup in `Django` which uses Django's **model form**. but I need to render my custom build `HTML` form in place of that.

My **models.py**:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class User(AbstractUser):
    is_student = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_teacher = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Student(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    quizzes = models.ManyToManyField(Quiz, through='TakenQuiz')
    interests = models.ManyToManyField(Subject, related_name='interested_students')
```

And **views.py**:

```
class StudentSignUpView(CreateView):
    model = User
    form_class = StudentSignUpForm
    template_name = 'registration/signup_form.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['user_type'] = 'student'
        return super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = form.save()
        login(self.request, user)
        return redirect('students:quiz_list')
```

This system has a form.py also which made the hard work and render the `Django` model form. Now I need to replace these types of Django's default **model form** with my custom build `HTML` form something like [this link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dldxB).
How can I use the following types of simple system which will receive data from `views.py` and will create a user?

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    this_username = request.POST['username']
    this_password = request.POST['password']
    this_otherKindofStuff = request.POST['otherKindofStuff']
    Student_signup = Student.objects.create(name=this_name, password=this_password, otherKindofStuff=this_otherKindofStuff)
    Student_signup.save()
```

current **forms.py**:

```
class StudentSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    interests = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Subject.objects.all(),
        widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,
        required=True
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User

    @transaction.atomic
    def save(self):
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.is_student = True
        user.save()
        student = Student.objects.create(user=user)
        student.interests.add(*self.cleaned_data.get('interests'))
        return user
```

My HTML **Template**:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="jumbotron">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="username" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
                    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Check me out</label>
                </div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<head>
    <!-- media query support -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1" />

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
```

Comment: Show your current `forms.py` and template code

Comment: edited.... and template has the only simple jinja for render Django's model form

Comment: So what you want to do is add custom styles or classes is that it? Can you also put a snippet from where your form is rendered in your HTML template?

Comment: yeah, I want it. HTML template is added also by a snippet. Here you can say there is nothing custom style or classes in this form, but I will add them later.

Comment: SO can you add an example of the expected HTML output?

Comment: I want to a make simple signup form. With help of Django's model form, I can easily create it. In this case, I just want to build my custom made form with HTML for this job. And I also expect the same type of output from it as Djnao's default model form gives us. So you can say this problem like 'How to render an HTML form which is used for signup purpose?'

Comment: And I need help to build my views.py for this. How it should be thus I can take data from a signup HTML form and put it in my database's user model(this user model is also custom build, given in question).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226406/discussion-between-redgren-grumbholdt-and-kanchon-gharami).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment:

> I just want to build my custom made form with HTML for this job

What I understood from that is you want to design your own HTML form, and do away with Django's default rendering? But be able to utilize Django's form logic.

If that's the case, all you need to collect form data to your view, is naming your custom fields the same names as in your `ModelForm` or simply `Form`. For example, if you have a form as follows:

```py
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
   field = forms.CharField()
   field2 = forms.IntegerField()
```

What you would do to create custom HTML for this form, provided you have already created the view and passed a `MyForm` instance to your context data ofcourse, is the following:

```html
...
<form method="post" action='.'>
   {% csrf_token %}
   <div class="my-custom-field-wrapper">
        <label for="field">Field</label>
        <input id="field" type="text" class="my-custom-field" />
   </div>
   
   <div class="my-custom-field-wrapper">
        <label for="field1">Field 1</label>
        <input id="field1" type="number" class="my-custom-field" />
   </div>
   <!-- buttons, etc -->
</form>
```

If the form above got submited the `POST`ed data would bind to the `MyForm` instance, and you'd be able to do your validations etc and also display errors in the template by accessing the `MyForm` instances's errors dict or per field.

Besides this, you can of course make use of Django forms's [widgets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/).

And also to add, you might be interested in trying out [django-crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/). If you're using Bootstrap for your HTML, this would be an excellent addition.

Comment: thanks a lot, that's what maybe I was looking for. I can able to access data from views.py by request.POST['field'] maybe?

Comment: Yes. You can. Let me add a snippet of what you can do after binding the POSTed data to your form.